# AWS SNS: Different policy for multiple SourceOwner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I need to register an external AWS account (ID: 222222222222) to an SNS topic that belongs to my main AWS account (ID: 111111111111).

I use serverless to create my different services and policies.

```
################################################
# SNS Topic Webhook OUT                         #
################################################
WebhookOutNotification:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    TopicName: ${opt:stage}-${opt:clientId}-webhook-out

################################################
# Policy for SNS Topic WebhookOutNotification  #
################################################
WebhookOutSNSPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: '*'
        Action:
          - sns:GetTopicAttributes
          - sns:SetTopicAttributes
          - sns:AddPermission
          - sns:RemovePermission
          - sns:DeleteTopic
          - sns:Subscribe
          - sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic
          - sns:Publish
          - sns:Receive
        Condition:
          StringEquals:
            aws:SourceOwner:
              - 111111111111
              - 222222222222
        Resource: !Ref WebhookOutNotification
    Topics:
      - Ref: WebhookOutNotification
```

Working, The configuration of my SNS topic from the AWS console:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sns:GetTopicAttributes",
        "sns:SetTopicAttributes",
        "sns:AddPermission",
        "sns:RemovePermission",
        "sns:DeleteTopic",
        "sns:Subscribe",
        "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "sns:Publish",
        "sns:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-3:301239487173:sbx-180420-webhook-out",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceOwner": [
            "111111111111",
            "222222222222"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It works but, I need to have different actions for each account listed in the policy.

For example:

On my serverless config, my main account is 111111111111.
The external account is 222222222222.

I need the main account 111111111111 to have all SNS actions listed in the action section.

But, I need the external account 222222222222 to have limited and specific actions. I would like the account 222222222222 to do **only** sns:Publish, not the other actions.

It's possible to do that?

Thank's a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
WebhookOutSNSPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Sid: __default_statement_ID
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: '*'
          Action:
            - SNS:GetTopicAttributes
            - SNS:SetTopicAttributes
            - SNS:AddPermission
            - SNS:RemovePermission
            - SNS:DeleteTopic
            - SNS:Subscribe
            - SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic
            - SNS:Publish
          Resource: !Ref WebhookOutNotification
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              AWS:SourceOwner: !Ref AWS::AccountId
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: arn:aws:iam::${opt:awsClientAccountId}:root
          Action: SNS:Subscribe
          Resource: !Ref WebhookOutNotification
    Topics:
      - Ref: WebhookOutNotification
```

This video helps me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Von_VgswnJU